# How to secure a Silverlight-Enabled WCF Web Service with SSL?

Tags: wcf, silverlight

How do you secure a Silverlight-Enabled WCF Web Service with SSL?  I have tried setting it up similar to a regular WCF service secured by SSL, but it doesn't seem to work.  What do you set in the *Web.Config*, and what do you set in the Silverlight's *ServiceReferences.ClientConfig*?

I noticed that in the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file of the Silverlight client app that the "Binding" tag only allows basicHttpBinding and NOT wsHttpBinding.  Does this mean that you can not secure a Silverlight-Enabled WCF Service?  If so are there better approaches to securing it?

Answer (score 11):

There are three key places that I configure to use https in my own apps.

**Web.config**

In the behavior tag include this line:

```
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
```

For the MEX endpoint, make sure you use the https protocol:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Create a custom binding. The important part is the transport security:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myServicesBinding">
      <security mode="Transport"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

You can also include the usual authorization stuff:

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="?"/>
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

**Silverlight**

On the Silverlight end, either point the ServiceReference at the now secure service, or set up the connections manually in code. the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file should have the security stuff in it:

```
<security mode="Transport"/>
```

And the code version looks like this:

```
BasicHttpBinding b = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
```

There are probably more complex things that can be done, but this should be good enough for most people.

Answer (score 3):

> in the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file of
> the Silverlight client app that the "Binding" tag only allows
> basicHttpBinding and NOT wsHttpBinding.
> Does this mean that you can not secure a Silverlight-Enabled
> WCF Service?

No, it doesn't mean that. You can have a `basicHttpBinding` and still assign transport-level security (HTTPS with SSL) to it. That shouldn't be a problem.

Marc

PS: Many one of those links gives you more insight and the proverbial "AHA!" :-)

- http://winterdom.com/2007/11/basichttpbindingwithtransportsecurity
- http://silverlight.net/forums/p/13275/44170.aspx
- http://kevindockx.blogspot.com/2009/02/username-authentication-with.html
- http://www.pixel73.com/blog/Default.aspx?g=posts&t=4173
- http://community.irritatedvowel.com/blogs/pete_browns_blog/archive/2008/03/19/WCF-Integration-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1.aspx
- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200128201134/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/scottthompson/archive/2009/03/25/setting-up-ssl-between-silverlight-and-wcf-under-iis7.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!  Though I'm confused as to what do I put in the Web.Config file that hosts the service?  Is it just basicHttpBinding with transport security?  I tried that and it returns a "Not Found" error.

Comment: Does your server that hosts the service have an SSL certificate installed and all? If you want to use SSL transport-level security, SSL at the transport level has to be setup correctly beforehand.

Comment: Yes, the site has a working SSL, I can access an .ASMX service using transport security and pointing it to https in the Silverlight config file.  But I can't for the life of me get it find a Silverlight-Enabled WFC service through https with transport security.

Comment: There's a number of ways you can set up transport security - just "transport", or "transportwithmessagecredentials" and another one I forget right now. I am not 100% sure what a Silverlight environment would expect - but basically, you have to have the same settings on both ends of your communications channel.

Answer (score 3):

To create Silverlight-Enabled WCF Web Service using SSL you have to do the following steps:

1. Create standard Silverlight-Enabled WCF Web Service using Visual Studio 2010
2. Change 3 places of webconfig.xml:

   a. In serviceMetadata change httpGetEnabled to httpsGetEnabled like this:

   ```
   <behaviors >
     <serviceBehaviors > 
       <behavior name="" > 
         <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
       </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   ```

   b. In binding change httpTransport to httpsTransport:

   ```
   <bindings>
     <customBinding>
       <binding name="Project.Web.YourService.customBinding0">
         <binaryMessageEncoding/>
         <httpsTransport/>
       </binding>
     </customBinding>
   </bindings>
   ```

   c. in endpoint change binding="mexHttpBinding" to binding="mexHttpsBinding":

   ```
   <service name="Project.Web.YourService.YourService">
     <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="Project.Web.YourService.customBinding0"
     contract="Project.Web.YourService.YourService" />
     <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
   </service>
   ```
3. Don't use ServiceReferences.ClientConfig. Create everything in code behind - it's easy to deploy on server:

   ```
   CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement(), new HttpsTransportBindingElement());         
   YourServiceReference.YourServiceClient service = new YourServiceReference.YourServiceClient (binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri( "https:yourhostname/YourService.svc").AbsoluteUri));        
   service.YourMethodCompleted += new EventHandler<YourServiceReference.YourMethodCompleted EventArgs>(service_YourMethodCompleted );
   service.YourMethodAsync();
   ```

Answer (score -2):

WS* is not supported in Silverlight - basically change the URL in the client config to be an https:// url - that's all you can do